# Restting password for primary Hotmail account on windows phone

Tags: microsoft-account

I do not want to do a hard reset as I am using phone, but I do not know the password. Can I reset the password somehow?

Answer (score 1):

You cannot change the password from your phone, other than by logging on in Internet Explorer and doing it from [there](https://account.microsoft.com/). If you do change your password via the Microsoft website (and to be honest, that's a lot easier to do on a normal PC), your phone will then prompt you to enter the new password without requiring a hard reset or losing any data.